# VueJS <ul> Throws Mismatched HTML - Caveat?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

VueJS is giving me this error on every page due to something in my header:

```
warn Parent:  
<ul class="nav">
warn Mismatching childNodes vs. VNodes:  
NodeList(13) [ <!--  -->, #text, <!--  -->, #text, li.nav-item, #text, li.nav-item, #text, li.nav-item.account, #text, … ]

error [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render. consola.browser.js:1:7123
error [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render. (repeated 1 times) consola.browser.js:1:7123
```

This is the source code for the header:

```html
<ul v-bind:class="{nav: true, toggled : bshow_nav }">           
    <li v-if="authd" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/profile">My Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li v-if="authd" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/payment">Payment Options</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="site.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="www.site.com/faq">F.A.Q.</a>
    </li>
    <li v-if="!authd" class="nav-item account">
        <a href="/signup" class="nav-link">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
    <li :class="{'nav-item' : true, 'account' : authd}">
        <a v-if="authd" href="#" class="nav-link" @click="logout">Logout</a>
        <a v-else class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class='nav-item nav-footer'>
        <img src="~/assets/images/logo.svg" alt="logo" width="60" height="60" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

this is it while rendered:

```html
<li class="nav-item"><a href="/profile" class="nav-link">My Profile</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="/payment" class="nav-link">Payment Options</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="https://mysitecom/privacy" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="https://mysitecom/faq" class="nav-link">F.A.Q.</a></li>
<!---->
<li class="nav-item account"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Logout</a></li>
<li class="nav-item nav-footer"><img src="/_nuxt/assets/images/logo.svg" alt="logo" width="60" height="60"></li>
```

My theory is that the `<!---->` is the reason because it expects all tags within the `<ul>` to be `<li>` tags.

Is there any way to ignore this or do some funky work around?

Comment: Please include error messages as text, not as images. Search engines don't crawl text in images, which means people searching for the same error message won't find your question (and its answers) easily.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok i did thank you, I never thought about that before, that's a good point